# The requested module '@glidejs/glide' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, glidejs

I have a svelte website & I'm using glidejs. Everything is working fine on my localhost, but once I deployed, I'm getting this error.
*I'm using node server adapter*

> SyntaxError: The requested module '@glidejs/glide' does not provide an export named 'default'

> at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)

> at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)

I'm importing glide correctly -it's working on localhost-

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';
```

What could be the reason & how to fix it?

The issue happened on render.com & a2hosting.com

Comment: What version of Node.js have you configured Render.com to use when executing your code?

Comment: @esqew 18.18.0 "lts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is gone once I imported glide like this

```
<svelte:head>
    <script src="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css" />
</svelte:head>
```

But still, I'm curious to know why it happens with **sveltekit** when it's imported like this `import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Glide with nuxt3 and has the same error, but as workaround I found that some, trick works for me:

```
import * as Glide from "@glidejs/glide";
```

then

```
new Glide.default(".glide", options).mount();
```

or just use another import:

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.esm'
```